# File gone after reboot when echo to file

Tags: ssh

I try to 'upload' certificate files to some linux based routers via ssh. As the used OpenWrt does not support sftp, I just directed the echo stream to a file

```
echo "--- cert content ---" > 'file.crt'
```

After that I run an MD5 checksum test to make sure that everything is written correctly.

It worked quite well so far. But now I faced the problem, that here and then the files are gone after a reboot.

Is it possible that with the echo command the file is not completely persisted, file handler closed or whatever, so that is gone after reboot? And if so, why does my MD5 check work?

I already asked the manufacturer if there is any job that might delete the file, which is not the case.

I am not an experience Linux user so I hope my question is not totally dumb ;)

The linux is a OpenWrt/Linaro GCC 4.8-2014.04

Regards and thanks,
Thomas

Comment: In what folder are you writing this? Try calling `sync` afterwards

Comment: At the moment it is in /lib/uci/upload as the UI uploads the data to that directory. But I will move it to etc/myApp as lib is not to best choice. There is no opt or similar...